# python changing keyboard language in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

I wrote python software that requires both german and english input. Currently, I am using the Mac shortcut cmd-space to quickly change keyboard layouts, but I need to do this hundreds of times, which slows things down. Since I know exactly when English vs German input is needed, is there a way to programmatically change the keyboard language in python?

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it isn't fun.

The method you're looking for is `TISSelectInputSource` and the related [TIS methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/). TIS is a Core Foundation library written in C. You will want to use [pyobjc](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/apinotes/CoreFoundation.html).

Once you're actually setup, the process is simple. Use [TISCreateInputSourceList](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/TISCreateInputSourceList) to get the `TISInputSourceRef` for the language you want to use and pass it to `TISSelectInputSource`.

Comment: This doesn't explain how you would use the API from Python, however.

Comment: @chepner I believe it does. pyobjc (and the specific page linked) is how you would use these these two functions from python. Remember that stackoverflow is for helping you solve a problem, not for doing all the work for you. The resulting python should be under 6 lines.

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked the reference to pyobjc.

Answer (score 0):

TkTech offers some general pointers, but it appears that pyobjc doesn't actually wrap the two Carbon methods you need (`TISCreateInputSourceList` and `TISSelectInputSource`). In fact, pyobjc discontinued Carbon support altogether in Python 3.

So yes, pyobjc is going to be helpful for calling Objective-C code in Python, but you're going to have to manually wrap those two methods you need, probably using `ctypes`. The code to do this is lengthier than it should be and a bit tedious, so I'll just link you to [my implementation](https://github.com/tigerjwang/pyinputlanguage/blob/main/pyinputlanguage.py).

Answer (score 0):

Calling xkbswitch from python using subprocess would probably be easier than the other solutions you find here.